# What if statement should I use that detects if Vimeo video is playing/paused?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, vimeo-api

What I want to do is create subtitles that will appear on the video. I need those subtitles to start appearing when I play the video, and I want them to pause when I pause the video. This is what I have:

```
  <script>
  var hour = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(0,1));
    var min = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(3,4));
    var seconds= parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(6,7));
    var mil_sec = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(9,11));
    var time = (hour*3600000)+(min*60000) +(seconds*1000)+mil_sec ;

    function timeout(){
    setTimeout(function()
    {


  if(true)
  {
  document.getElementById('subs').innerHTML = js_arr[i];
              i=i+4;
            j=j+4;
            hour = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(0,1));
            min = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(3,4));
            seconds = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(6,7));
            mil_sec = parseInt(js_arr[j].substring(9,11));
            time = (hour*3600000)+(min*60000)+(seconds*1000)+mil_sec;

            timeout();
     }
      else{
        timeout();
      }


    },time);
}

</script>
```

I am stuck on what is supposed to be in the if statement to make it do what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation at http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api one can see that there is a function:

> paused():Boolean  Returns false if the video is playing, true
>   otherwise.

You think you could use that?

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

You can add events to this player using these code:

```
var iframe = $('#player1')[0],
player = $f(iframe),
status = $('.status');

// When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
status.text('ready');

player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
});

// Call the API when a button is pressed
$('button').bind('click', function() {
     player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
 });

 function onPause(id) {
   status.text('paused');
}

function onFinish(id) {
status.text('finished');
}

 function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
}
```

Thanks

JFIT